# Django MultpleSelectionField usage and error

Tags: python, django, multiplechoicefield

I have the following code

**models.py**

```
fitness_choices = (('wl', 'Weight Loss'), ('ft', 'Firming and Toning'),
                   ('yo', 'Yoga'), ('ot', 'Others'), )
periods_to_train = (('da', 'Daily'), ('ft', 'Few Times A Week'),
                    ('oa', 'Once A Week'), )

class Fitness(models.Model):
    fitness_goals = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=fitness_choices)
    training_periods = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=periods_to_train)
```

**forms.py**

```
class FitnessForm(ModelForm):
    fitness_goals = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=fitness_choices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    training_periods = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
          model = Fitness
```

**views.py**

```
from apps.services.forms import FitnessForm

def fitness(request):
    """ Creating a Fitness RFQ """
    fitness_rfq_form = FitnessForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fitness_rfq_form = FitnessForm(request.POST)
        if fitness_rfq_form.is_valid():
            obj = fitness_rfq_form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    context = {'fitness_rfq_form': fitness_rfq_form}
    return render(request, 'services/fitness_rfq.html', context)
```

But when i am trying to submit i am getting the validation error as below

```
Select a valid choice. [u'wl', u'ft'] is not one of the available choices.

Select a valid choice. [u'0', u'1'] is not one of the available choices.
```

So why it was showing above validation error even though we have mentioned it as MultiplechoiceField in ModelForm ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify `choices` in the model field... this is the part that is failing validation.

Your form is working fine and the result of the multiple choice field is, of course, a list of selected choices.  But then your model field is expecting a single value from the `choices`.

If you want to store the list of selected choices in a CharField you need to convert them to a string first, perhaps via `json.dumps`